# DataGridView cambiar color de fondo

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un datagridview el cual le cambio de color de fondo en la propiedad BackGroundColor pero cuando ejecuto la app el color de fondo se ve como si no lo huviese cambiado.

¿Como puedo hacer para que en tiempo de ejecución se vea el color cambiado del DataGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación la propiedad BackgroundColor debería de cambiar el color del DataGridView.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.backgroundcolor(v=vs.100).aspx

Es importante recordar también que esta propiedad cambia el color por defecto del espacio no lleno por celdas aun, por lo que podrías probar con el siguiente código si tu intención es cambiar de color de fondo de un control lleno de datos.

```
private void dgvStatus_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != color.Index)
        return;

    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(((DataRowView)dgvStatus.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row[4].ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Hola Joel, ya hice lo de la propiedad BackGroudColor en tiempo de diseño cambie el color pero en tiempo de ejecución mantine el color que viene por default.

Comment: Podrias probar definiendo el valor de la propiedad en el evento Load del formulario justo debajo de this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

Comment: Funciono poniendo el color en el load